# Calculating velocity from speed and direction

Tags: c++, sfml, trigonometry, angle

I have an object which wants to move from point A to point B, at a certain speed (using SFML C++).

```
sf::Vector2f aPos; //sf::Vector2f has two members x and y, stored as floats
sf::Vector2f bPos;
float speed; //pixels per tick
```

I want to use these variables to find out a velocity, with an x speed and a y speed, such that the hypotenuse of `vel.x` and `vel.y` has length `speed`, and has the same bearing as that from point `aPos` to point `bPos`.

```
sf::Vector2f vel;
```

What is the simplest and most effective function that I can write, which takes `sf::Vector2f aPos`, `sf::Vector2f bPos` and `float speed` as arguments, and returns `sf::Vector2f vel`

```
sf::Vector2f findVel(sf::Vector2f aPos, sf::Vector2f bPos, float speed) {
    sf::Vector2f vel;
    //the code I need
    return vel;
}
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Scale the direction vector `d` with `speed/||d||`.

Comment: Design wise, it's probably better to decompose this into smaller functions (which you'll find youself using a lot), such as a function for getting a vector from 2 positions, calculating a vectors norm, and for normalizing a vector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking k_g's answer, we can actually shorten it quite a bit given that `Vector2f` has operator overloads. It can simply become:

```
sf::Vector2f findVel(const sf::Vector2f& aPos, const sf::Vector2f& bPos, float speed) {
    sf::Vector2f disp = bPos-aPos;
    float distance    = sqrt(disp.x*disp.x+disp.y*disp.y); // std::hypot(disp.x, disp.y) if C++ 11
    return disp * (speed/distance);
}
```

This also allows us to benefit from any optimizations that might have been built into the `Vector` class for operations.

Note the change to `const &` for the input parameters; no need to make a copy of them since you aren't manipulating them.

Comment: Consider using `std::hypot` to compute the distance (if C++11 is an option). It might be considerable faster than rolling out the computation explicitly, and it is probably more readable

Answer (score 4):

well, we know that `speed == distance/time` and `velocity == displacement/time`.

Solving for `1/time` in the first equation, we get `1/time==speed/distance`. We substitute this into the second equation to get `velocity == displacement*speed/distance`.

Using this formula, we get the following function

```
sf::Vector2f findVel(sf::Vector2f aPos, sf::Vector2f bPos, float speed) {
    sf::Vector2f vel;
    float dispx = bPos.x-aPos.x;
    float dispy = bPos.y-aPos.y;
    float distance = sqrt(dispx*dispx+dispy*dispy);
    vel.x = dispx*speed/distance;
    vel.y = dispy*speed/distance;
    return vel;
}
```

Comment: @Yaxlat Please tell me if some of the floating point arithmetic is wrong; I'm not that experienced at C++

Comment: it works perfectly, however aruisdante's submission is an improvement. Thanks a lot for your help!